# Need to Handle IF condition in PL/SQL BULK Collect For Loop

Tags: sql, plsql, lookup, bulk

Team,
I have source table

```
SRC_TBL 
--------------  
STATUS EMP_ID
--------------
VALID   E1
VALID   E2
VALID   E3
VALID   E4
VALID   E5
VALID   E6
INVALID E7
INVALID E8
VALID   E9
VALID   E10
VALID   E11
VALID   E12
VALID   E13
VALID   E14
```

1. Need to pick from SRC_TBL with `STATUS ='VALID'` and feed table `TAR_TBL`
2. Divide the total VALID records into batches with `BATCH_ID` with 5 recs/batch
3. This divide value `5` will be passed as parameter. Real case can be `100 or 200` per batch.
4. Sample data is just few here. Real case 10000+records in `SRC_TBL` table
5. Hence need to handle in BULK COLLECT
6. But use of IF/WHEN is not allowed in BULK COLLECT's forallin loop

TAR_TBL

```
STATUS  EMP_ID  BATCH_ID
VALID   E1      1
VALID   E2      1
VALID   E3      1
VALID   E4      1
VALID   E5      1
VALID   E6      2
VALID   E9      2
VALID   E10     2
VALID   E11     2
VALID   E12     2
VALID   E13     3
VALID   E14     3
```

Comment: Why do you store EMP_ID's as character data? This means comparisons (incl order by) become much trickier. E.g. `E14 < E2`, while `14 > 2`.

Comment: EMP_ID is not in ORDER. Real case it would be some alphanumeric and jumbled one. But will be unique value in the column.  I hope index by binary_integer will work?

Comment: Does the EMP_ID order, or any order, matter when it comes to BATCH_ID?

Comment: No. Just 5 ( or any parameter value  ) per batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code for your question.

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR c_src IS
    SELECT EMP_ID
    FROM SRC_TBL
    WHERE STATUS = 'VALID';

  TYPE emp_id_array IS TABLE OF SRC_TBL.EMP_ID%TYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  l_emp_ids emp_id_array;

  v_batch_size NUMBER := 5; -- You can change this to 100 or 200 based on your requirement.
  v_batch_id NUMBER := 1;

BEGIN
  OPEN c_src;

  LOOP
    FETCH c_src BULK COLLECT INTO l_emp_ids LIMIT v_batch_size;

    FORALL i IN 1..l_emp_ids.COUNT
      INSERT INTO TAR_TBL (STATUS, EMP_ID, BATCH_ID)
      VALUES ('VALID', l_emp_ids(i), v_batch_id);

    EXIT WHEN c_src%NOTFOUND;

    v_batch_id := v_batch_id + 1;
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE c_src;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks Ela for the answer ! What if we have to skip creating the TAR_TBL and create new column BATCH_ID in SRC_TBL itself and update. Will this approach work instead create new table. So we can mark INVALID rows with BATCH_ID=0? Will that need any MERGE?

Answer (score 1):

No need for PL/SQL code, simply do an INSERT with SELECT. Use `row_number()` window function to number the rows, and do a basic calculation to get 5 rows per batch.

```
insert into tar_tbl (STATUS, EMP_ID, BATCH_ID)
  select status, emp_id, trunc((rowno + 5 - 1) / 5) batch_id
  from (
    select status, emp_id, row_number() over (order by status) rowno
    from src_tbl 
    where status = 'VALID'
  ) dt
```

Replace the two (!) 5's with another number to adjust the batch size.

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/jdifUOdo

Comment: am getting sql statement ignored when use this query in my procedure  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78041309/getting-sql-statement-ignored-in-procedure) _italic_ **bold**

Comment: The first comment says "The insert statement needs to be terminated by a semi colon. Change ") dst" to ") dst;" "