# Getting SQL statement ignored in procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Am getting pl/sql statement ignored error in my pl/sql procedure where `SELECT` starts in sql developer while compile

```
PROCEDURE sort_emp_records (
        p_instance_id   IN VARCHAR2,
        p_filename      IN VARCHAR2,
        p_max_batch_rec IN NUMBER,
        x_status_code   OUT VARCHAR2,
        x_error_message OUT VARCHAR2
    ) IS
BEGIN
insert into LCK_EMPLY_TARG_TBL
select VAL_STATUS trunc((rowno + p_max_batch_rec - 1) / p_max_batch_rec) LOOP_SET_ID
from (
  select VAL_STATUS, emp_id, row_number() over (order by status) rowno
  from LCK_EMPLY_SRC_TBL 
  where VAL_STATUS = 'VALID'
) dst
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        x_status_code := sqlcode;
        x_error_message := sqlerrm;
END sort_emp_records;
```

Comment: The insert statement needs to be terminated by a semi colon. Change ") dst" to ") dst;"

Comment: there are several errors in your PLSQL code, and some boilerplate code. Firstly, it seems that there is a lack of separator or operator between `VAL_STATUS ` and `trunc((rowno + p_max_batch_rec - 1) / p_max_batch_rec)` field. Another one is lack of the semicolon at the end of a query. Just because of im curious- why you even use an alias called `dst` if you dont make use of it in your query?

Comment: ALready tried  --> Error: PL/SQL: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: @BalaganeshMohanavel that's because of lack of separator or operator between `VAL_STATUS` and `trunc((rowno + p_max_batch_rec - 1) / p_max_batch_rec)` field. How many columns do you have in your `LCK_EMPLY_TARG_TBL` table ?

Comment: 29 columns are there in my LCK_EMPLY_TARG_TBL

Comment: @BalaganeshMohanavel so how your PLSQL procedure is going to know, where you want to put those 2 columns that you do select? Remember, always mention a person you are replying to with `@` so the person you reply gets notified.

Comment: Thanks for throwing light.

Comment: Also, is there a reason why you are using PL/SQL at all? There might be, if your app is intentionally designed to interact with tables exclusively through procedure calls. But otherwise, there's nothing that PL/SQL is doing for you here outside of the SQL  insert itself. In most cases, you should just use normal SQL and dispense with any procedural wrapper for such basic actions.

Comment: okay sure. heard Bulk COLLECT useful wrt timing for 10000+ records. Hence wanted to try that

Comment: `bulk collect` is only useful when you already need PL/SQL for other reasons and need to load a collection (array) for further procedural processing. Nothing in PL/SQL is faster/better than straight SQL for normal data manipulation. Only use PL/SQL if you need to employ procedural logic for some reason that you can't do in SQL. SQL is pretty powerful - learn it well, and only then start branching out into more advanced PL/SQL-based solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you are missing your column names in your insert query. In the comments section you said that your table has 26 columns, you need to point them out by doing something like this:

```
insert into LCK_EMPLY_TARG_TBL (column_name_1,column_name_2)
```

Another case is that you are missing a separator between your columns in the select:

```
select VAL_STATUS
       ,trunc((rowno + p_max_batch_rec - 1) / p_max_batch_rec) LOOP_SET_ID
```

The last problem with your query you are missing a semicolon at the end, as it was previously mentioned by @KoenLostrie in the comment secion.

Finally, your code should more or less look like this (you have to only replace `column_name_1`,`column_name_2` to the real column names that you want to put your values from the select query):

```
PROCEDURE sort_emp_records (
        p_instance_id   IN VARCHAR2,
        p_filename      IN VARCHAR2,
        p_max_batch_rec IN NUMBER,
        x_status_code   OUT VARCHAR2,
        x_error_message OUT VARCHAR2
    ) IS
BEGIN
insert into LCK_EMPLY_TARG_TBL (column_name_1,column_name_2)
select VAL_STATUS, trunc((rowno + p_max_batch_rec - 1) / p_max_batch_rec) LOOP_SET_ID
from (
  select VAL_STATUS, emp_id, row_number() over (order by status) rowno
  from LCK_EMPLY_SRC_TBL 
  where VAL_STATUS = 'VALID'
) dst;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        x_status_code := sqlcode;
        x_error_message := sqlerrm;
END sort_emp_records;
```

Comment: done..compiled now!!

Comment: @BalaganeshMohanavel Consider marking my answer as an correct one if it solves the question you asked.

Comment: Yes it is correct Bartoz